# We toss three coins (each with pr(heads)= p). Let X be the number of heads that occur on the first two tosses and Y be the number of heads..

Tags: probability

that occur on tosses 2 and 3. range of X = range of Y = {0,1,2}

[image]

Does this work seem at all correct? I am stumped with this problem... I'm not sure how to approach it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For part c), we have that $p(y|x) = \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}$ by definition, so you should be able to solve for $p(x,y)$.

Comment: @eigenchris so $p(y|x) p(x) = p(x,y)$? But how de we get those values? Do I just sum the rows?

Comment: you can calculate p(x) with a binomial distribution, then you ask yourself if I know there was x heads on first two what is probability that there was y heads on second and third toss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) If I see it right, than you have to calculate $P(Y=y_i|X=x_i) \ \forall \ i,j=1,2,3$

$P(Y=0 |X=0)$:

For X=0, you have the permutations $TTH,TTT$, because the first two tosses have no heads.

Given this two events, what is the probability, that the tosses 2,3 are $TT$ ? The only event (of the 2), which fullfill the condition is $TTT$

Thus it is $P(Y=0 |X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$

All clear ?

Comment: So even thought $pr(heads) = p$ we still get that $P(Y=0|X=0) = \frac{1}{2}$ because there are only 2 possible permutations and half of those are the correct outcome?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @user161154 No, It is $P(Y=0 \cap X=0)=f(0,0)=(1-p)^3=0,125$. This is the probability which you need for part c). And the probability P(X=0) is not $(1-p^2)$. It is 1/4. From the 8 permutations, the are only the two permutations, $TTT,TTH$, where you have no heads at the first two tosses. Oh, you have deleted your second comment.

Comment: hmm now I am confused... so $pr(heads) = p$ doesn't factor into this problem then?

Comment: pr(heads)=p=1/2 means only, that you have a chance of a half, that you get head, if you toss one coin. It is important to know. But you have to go further.

Comment: but this problem wants you to take the probability of a coin being heads to be $p$ not $\frac{1}{2}$. As this is not stated to be a fair coin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15864/discussion-between-calculus-and-user161154).

Comment: okay not sure how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

There are only $8$ outcomes of the first $3$ tosses, so you can just list them out:

$TTT$ - $(X,Y) = (0,0)$ - prob $(1-p)^3$

$TTH$ - $(X,Y) = (0,1)$ - prob $p(1-p)^2$

$THT$ - $(X,Y) = (1,1)$ - prob $p(1-p)^2$

$THH$ - $(X,Y) = (1,2)$ - prob $p^2(1-p)$

$HTT$ - $(X,Y) = (1,0)$ - prob $p(1-p)^2$

$HTH$ - $(X,Y) = (1,1)$ - prob $p^2(1-p)$

$HHT$ - $(X,Y) = (2,1)$ - prob $p^2(1-p)$

$HHH$ - $(X,Y) = (2,2)$ - prob $p^3$

Now, you should be able to complete the table.

Comment: Since $(X,Y) = (1,1)$ shows up twice do I multiply the probabilities?

Comment: I meant sum them?

Comment: notice that all the (X,Y) combos you have in table is sample space, where (1,1) only shows up once

Comment: $\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,1)] = \Pr[THT \ \text{OR} \ HTH] = \Pr[THT]+\Pr[HTH]$ since the events $THT$ and $HTH$ are disjoint. So yes, you do add them.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Okay that makes sense! So my first cell should be actually be $(1-p)$